# Circuit diagram to html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have requirement to do convert below image to HTML page

**Note:** We should not use images.
[image]

I am new to this kind of design, So any suggestion will be grateful.

Comment: Why use HTML? Why not something more appropriate like SVG?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DragNode chart](http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/drag-node-charts/) of FusionCharts to achieve it.

```
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/4B6M4/).

Answer (score 0):

Consider also GoJS, such as this sample: http://gojs.net/latest/samples/processFlow.html
There are other samples like it that you can see at http://gojs.net/latest/samples/index.html